# Getting Entity Framework to update both normal and relational fields

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I have a problem figuring out the proper way to get foreign key fields to update using the Entity Framework.  I do not have a problem updating them in the database, but rather on the interface.

Here are the relevant tables to my question
file:///C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/RelevantTables.bmp

I have a "Team" form with a Master/Detail type view (master = Team, detail = Player), and show the Players in a ListView.  When you double click a Player, I show the "Edit Player" form.

Here is how I am loading the data in my TeamForm Window_Loaded event:

```
var TeamQuery = from t in ScoresDB.Team
    .Include("School").Include("TeamLevel").Include("Player.PlayerPosition")
    .Where(x => x.TeamID == TeamID)
    select t;

TeamData = new TeamCollection(TeamQuery, ScoresDB);                    

TeamViewSource = (CollectionViewSource)FindResource("TeamViewSource");
PlayerViewSource = (CollectionViewSource)FindResource("PlayerViewSource");
TeamViewSource.Source = TeamData;

TeamView = (ListCollectionView)TeamViewSource.View;
TeamView.CurrentChanged += new EventHandler(TeamView_CurrentChanged);

PlayerView = (BindingListCollectionView)PlayerViewSource.View;
```

This is what I am doing when the user wants to edit a player:

```
// If the user made changes to the player, then refresh our view
if (PlayerForm.EditPlayer(SelectedPlayer.PlayerID)) {
    ScoresDB.Refresh(System.Data.Objects.RefreshMode.ClientWins, PlayerView);
}
```

My problem is that, although every field that is not a foreign key does reflect the changes in the ListView, the PlayerPosition does not.  It is being properly changed in the database.  Do I need to re-query the database every time?

I get the distinct feeling that I am doing all of this quite poorly as I am just starting to trudge through WPF and EF.

If anyone has a clue what is going on or just wishes to tell me how silly I am being doing it this way, that is fine with me!

Thanks in advance,
Mike

Comment: Sorry for the reference to my bitmap.  This is my first time posting on StackOverflow!  I also forgot to mention that I am Binding to the Master and Detail views using {Binding Source} tags in my XAML.

Comment: You could upload your bitmap to e.g. www.tinypic.com and then post the link here - someone with enough reputation can then update your post :-)

Comment: Sure, no problem.  I don't think the bitmap is critical to the question, just a capture of the relevant edmx tables.  Here is the link:  http://i31.tinypic.com/2u4mrmd.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am either completely retarded, way too tired, or both.  I vote both!  :)

This required exactly one line of code, namely calling the very appropriately named Refresh() method for my BindingListCollectionView (PlayerView).

So I simply change my Edit Player if block as follows:

```
if (PlayerForm.EditPlayer(SelectedPlayer.PlayerID)) {
    ScoresDB.Refresh(System.Data.Objects.RefreshMode.ClientWins, PlayerView);
    // Added this line and it works
    PlayerView.Refresh();
}
```

I hope no one spent too much time on this one.  I am not totally sure why the non relational fields do update when I simply update the database, but it works now so that's at least something!

Thanks,
Mike